# HTML/CSS Text and Icon vertically centered in same line

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have to center those icons vertically center to the text. But its off for a few pixel. I have tried a bunch of stuff now but thats the best I could come up with. Any idea why it is not working?

HTML

```
<div class="listItem" >
  <div class="listItem__pre">
    <span class="icon icon--account-logout"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="listItem__content">
    <p>Max Muster</p>
  </div>

  <div class="listItem__post">
    <span class="icon icon--account-logout"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.listItem {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.listItem__content {
  flex-grow: 1;

  > * {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.listItem__pre {
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
  align-self: center;
}

.listItem__post {
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
  align-self: center;
}
```

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZMJu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.listItem {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  align-items: center
}
```

On `listItem` class, add this css option: `align-items: center`